# A Modest Proposal for Preventing Robo-Approvers From Being a Burden to The Community

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, robots

Just an idea for the developers to toy with:

How about putting the "Skip" button first?

Just that. Or possibly do some A-B testing, to see what happens, though changing it *for the same user* could be rather frustrating (but it would keep them on their toes!).

Or better than that, even consider *completely reversing* the order of the buttons: this makes them 'safest' first, no?

[image]

Comment: They don't get badges for skipping, do they?

Comment: @Asad, good point. Personally, I've never really seen badges as an incentive, so I have difficulty taking that mindset into account.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the *only* mindset a robo-reviewer has.

Comment: What other incentive is there for a robo reviewer?

Comment: @Asad, getting rid of that annoying orange number :)

Comment: It only annoys you if you give a sh_t about the site. Clearly this is not the case with the target audience.

Comment: ideally, buttons should be re-hashed in random order at every new item displayed to reviewer. This would make a burden to robo reviewers, and on the other hand would be not much of an issue to those who put _most effort_ in studying the item content :)

Comment: It has been proposed to add a "Gimme the badge" button as well. That way it only takes one click, and saves time for everyone.

Comment: @BoPersson I have a better suggestion that's been suggested and declined over and over again - remove the badge.

Comment: @gnat You'd also need to randomise the id/name of the DOM element, to prevent userscripts from automating the process anyway.

Comment: Randomize the order of the buttons.

Comment: @Won't ,gnat I'm pretty sure that would lead to a lot of mistakes on the part of well intentioned reviewers, while not really slowing robo reviewers down significantly. Then again, you're probably joking.

Comment: @J.Steen `$('input[value="Approve"]').click();`? Short of labeling the "Approve" button with the text "Skip", there isn't much you can do to combat userscripts.

Comment: @Asad You could use cryptic, randomised and invisible unicode in the name. Or something.